# Best Linux Screencasts Video Learning Series For New Ruby on Rails Developer?

Tags: linux, video

I love the sites for learning rails like lynda.com, railscasts.com and codeschool.com. Is there any similar sites for learning linux?

Specifically like a 1 - 2 hour screencasts series I want to get better at:

1) Command line
2) Package installation
3) Web server

the stuff a Ruby on Rails developer needs to know. I've done a bit of poking around and found: http://www.theurbanpenguin.com which looks really good, but I was wondering what your favorites are?

Answer (score 0):

I've watched [Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/) which I liked alot.